# How can I delete a file from external storage from different packages in android? Do I have this permission?

Tags: android, file

I want to delete a file from external storage for example with path:

```
String path = "/whatsapp/images/myfile.jpg"
```

I use codes below to delete this file , but not worked:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path);



public void delete(File file,Context context){
    if(file.exists()){
        boolean deleted = file.delete();
        Toast.makeText(context,"File Successfully removed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"File is not here!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

also I write necessary permissions in manifest file.

Comment: where is the actual implementation of the deleting of the file?

Comment: Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() and share logcat